# Connnect firebase-admin storage to firebbase emulator in python

Tags: python, firebase-storage, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

I am using firebase-admin with python to access storage buckets and it works fine with my real project. But now I want to connect it to the firebase emulator instead of a real bucket.

I looked at the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage#admin_sdks and I have already added the FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable like this:
`export FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9199"`
Now I wanted to use the fake emulated storage bucket instead of the real one and this is the code I have so far:

```
from firebase_admin import storage
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate('key.json')

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

bucket = storage.bucket("<project_id>.appspot.com") # what am I supposed to put here
```

With this code it just uses the real firebase storage bucket.
I have also tried putting `127.0.0.1:9199` as the bucket name, but it gives the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/127.0.0.1:9199/o?projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: The specified bucket does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set env like this:

```
STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST=http://localhost:9199
```

Worked for me

Comment: I have already done this. What I need to know is what I put here: bucket = storage.bucket("<project_id>.appspot.com") # what am I supposed to put here. Just to make sure, have you tested this with python?

Comment: no, i mean not FIREBASE_STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST as documentation says, but STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST instead. For the bucket name i just put nothing like this:

```
bucket = storage.bucket()
```

but when initializing the app I do:


```
cred = credentials.Certificate(firebase_key_file_path)
initialize_app(
    cred,
    {
        "storageBucket": "<project_id>.appspot.com",
    },
)
```

Comment: Sorry for not reading your answer right. It worked, Thanks a lot!! Do you know why the documentation says it wrong?

Comment: Probably repo was changed and the documentation was not updated.
I've also stumbled upon this issue and I had to go through the source code to find out what is the correct way to set up the environment variables.